# Product Order form where row is added when clicked on a button

Tags: php, forms

i would like to create an order form where the fields are

Select Customer: [dropdown menu]
Select Product: [dropdown menu] Quantity: [] UnitPrice:[query from db when product is selected] TotalPrice: [displayed when product is selected and updated when quantity is updated]

[Add product button] [Submit button] [Reset]

so my questions:

1. the add row button should add the form fields From Select Product. Each of this row should have a unique id as they are different rows in the db. Any help is greatly appreciated.
2. how do i trigger the unitprice and totalprice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems all client side request, so i suggest you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to solve your problem. All the function i will use inside my example can be find on that site, and there's plenty of example here on stackoverflow to solve all your doubt.
Now to the questions:

1.
I didn't really get what you want but you should simply generate an event on the addRow button using the click event:

```
$('AddRow').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //this avoid the default button action (submit/send)
var last_id = $('row').last().attr('id'); //retrieve the id of the last added row you probably will have to strip/transform it since id shouldn't be only number
$('row').last().append('insert here html with form fields of the new row with the (last_id+1)');
});
```

2.
To retrieve the UnitPrice you should use an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call ,use an `$('product').change(function(){});` to trigger the event and retrieve via ajax the result. As soon as you have populated that field you can use a simple jquery/javascript function to dinamically calculate the Total Price based on the Quantity field:

```
$('Quantity').change(function(){
     //add here control to check if fields are empty/wrongly set
    var UnitPrice = parseFloat($('UnitPrice').val());
    var Quantity = parseInt($('Quantity').val());
    $('TotalPrice').val(UnitPrice*Quantity);
})
```